# Firefox plugin for a web developer that shows all resources (js, css, html) as a single unified file?

Tags: firefox, plugins, resources, merge

I'm developing with a really complex cms system, and sometimes I need to know if something was sent to my html rendering.

Since this is a huge cms system, I have at least 30 resources linked to a page (js, css), and going through each one, clicking and searching for a string is not the best way to do it.

I would like to have a plugin that gets all the resources from a page, merges them as text, so i can search only once. Is this possible? Does something like this exists?

(I know Firebug can inspect an element and such, but a search option for an specific scenario - like a `type=submit` somewhere in a css file - is faster and more useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you need is the [Web Developers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/) toolbar addon for Firefox.

- You can search all JavaScript files in plain text by clicking **Information -> View JavaScript**
- You can search all CSS files in plain text by clicking **CSS -> View CSS**

Comment: I would like to have to click just once, but having to click 3 times instead of 30 is still a good idea. I'm going to waut for more suggestions. :)

Answer (score 0):

In firebug, when you inspect an element it shows all CSS rules applying to it and a link to the source file involved. I think it is away more powerful then what you want.

Comment: I'm already using firebug. In some situations a search approach is faster and more useful.