# find out if a web page used font substitution

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

Whats a fast and easy way to find out if a web page uses font substitution (like css @font-face)?

Currently I look a the css source code, but that takes to long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer [Firefox plugin for a web developer that shows all resources (js, css, html) as a single unified file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972591/firefox-plugin-for-a-web-developer-that-shows-all-resources-js-css-html-as-a#answer-3972748)

If you use that firefox plug in it will only take 3 keyboard commands

1. Crtl + Shift + C    (view all css)
2. Crtl + f   (find)
3. Type in   @font-face

Cannot be any quicker then that, unless you want to write some javascript code

Comment: thanks for the answer, sounds like a good idea. I am also checking now the FontFinder Plugin for firefox, but I am not sure if that always reports the font substitution. So I will check out your method and then accept the answer.